# Change root view controller of AppDelegate cause an exception of UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, appdelegate

Outside the `AppDelegate`, I want to change the `rootViewController` of it. In other words, I want to put a new navigation controller on top of what I had before in my window and then push the new controller in this navigation controller:

```
func JumpToPage(_ controller: UIViewController) {
        guard let rootController = AppDelegate.shared?.presentationViewController else {
            return
        }
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootController)
        navigationController.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
        AppDelegate.shared?.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
    }
}
```

But this function cause the app to crash with the following error message:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency',
    reason: 'adding a root view controller <MyExampleController> as a child of view controller:<UINavigationController>'
```

How should I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Change from

```
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootController)
```

To

```
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
```

**Update**

```
func JumpToPage(_ controller: UIViewController) {
    guard let rootController = AppDelegate.shared?.presentationViewController else {
        return
    }
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
    AppDelegate.shared?.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
}
```

Comment: I want the to put the navigation controller on top of what I had before in my window and then push the new controller in it, so this solution couldn't help it

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to replace navigation controller, I'm replacing root VC in the initial navigation controller as follows.

In AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions ...) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "FirstVC", bundle: Bundle.main)
    let firstViewController = instantiateInitialViewController()! as! FirstViewController
    navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: firstViewController)
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window!.rootViewController = navigationController
    window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```

Then, I change root VC w/in FirstViewController as follows:

```
func someFuncInFirstVC() {
    let allControllers = NSMutableArray(array: self.navigationController!.viewControllers)
    allControllers.removeObject(at: allControllers.count - 1)  // remove root VC, count should be one...
    let secondViewController = SecondViewController()
    allControllers.add(secondViewController as AnyObject)  // this becomes new root VC since nav stack is empty now
    navigationController!.setViewControllers(allControllers as [AnyObject] as! [UIViewController], animated: true)
}
```